# how to center content inside stack view in Storyboard?

Tags: swift, storyboard

I'm trying to recreate the following page:

[image]

My idea was to divide the screen to three parts and have a stack for each one.
When i create the upper Stack (everything that's in the red backgorund in the image) i cannot center my content inside of it.

How could i center my content inside of the stack view ?

Here is what i have done :

[image]

Comment: You have to do fill & fill equally or give a height to elements with fill & fill

Comment: Thnx for the comment Ali, I tried fill & fill equally it just devided it into 3 pieces, and didn't really centered them in the center

Comment: I guess you have a constraint at image. What is that ?

Comment: It's just height and width constrains

Comment: delete width constraint. It is equal to stack width. you're missing a spot . Can you share file inspector screenshot properly ?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the axis is `vertical`, alignment is `center`, and distribution is `equal spacing`.

And you should remove the height constraint of the stackview.